# How do I create a color matrix in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm looking to use the ColorFiltered widget to apply a color saturation matrix but don't know how to make the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case i solved it following way:

```
class CustomSubFilters extends ColorFilter {
  CustomSubFilters.matrix(List<double> matrix) : super.matrix(matrix);

  ///defaults to unity matrix when s = 0;
  factory CustomSubFilters.saturate(double sat) {
    num x = 1 + sat;
    num lumR = 0.3086;
    num lumG = 0.6094;
    num lumB = 0.0820;

return CustomSubFilters.matrix(<double>[
  lumR * (1 - x) + x,
  lumG * (1 - x),
  lumB * (1 - x),
  0,
  0,
  lumR * (1 - x),
  lumG * (1 - x) + x,
  lumB * (1 - x),
  0,
  0,
  lumR * (1 - x),
  lumG * (1 - x),
  lumB * (1 - x) + x,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  0,
]);
```

}

Of course you are flexible with the implementation just don't forget to extend the ColorFilter class.